# Why am I getting errors with libraries when trying compile masm32 file?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I have file like that starts like this:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 1000h

include C:\masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
```

and masm32rt.inc like this (I added C:/ to the paths, because it gave other errors):

```
      .486                                      ; create 32 bit code
      .model flat, stdcall                      ; 32 bit memory model
      option casemap :none                      ; case sensitive 

;     include files
;     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc       ; main windows include file
      include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc        ; masm32 library include

    ; -------------------------
    ; Windows API include files
    ; -------------------------
      include C:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc
      include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc
      include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
      include C:\masm32\include\Comctl32.inc
      include C:\masm32\include\comdlg32.inc
      include C:\masm32\include\shell32.inc
      include C:\masm32\include\oleaut32.inc
      include C:\masm32\include\ole32.inc
      include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc

      include C:\masm32\include\dialogs.inc       ; macro file for dialogs
      include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm         ; masm32 macro file

;     libraries
;     ~~~~~~~~~
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib         ; masm32 static library

    ; ------------------------------------------
    ; import libraries for Windows API functions
    ; ------------------------------------------
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\Comctl32.lib
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\comdlg32.lib
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\shell32.lib
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\oleaut32.lib
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\ole32.lib
      includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

; «««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««
```

And it gives warnings like this so the exe file doesn't work:

`LINK : warning L4051: \masm32\lib\masm32.lib : cannot find library                                                                         LINK : warning L4051: \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib : cannot find library                                                                          LINK : warning L4051: \masm32\lib\user32.lib : cannot find library                                                                         LINK : warning L4051: \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib : cannot find library                                                                       LINK : warning L4051: \masm32\lib\Comctl32.lib : cannot find library`                                                                 
And similar warnings

What do I do wrong?
My .bat file to compile the main file looks like this:

```
c:\masm32\bin\ml /c tat.asm
c:\masm32\bin\link16 tat.obj
```

Comment: Well, do those lib files exist in that location on your computer?

Comment: Also, `link16` is the linker for 16-bit (DOS) programs. You should be using `link` if you're trying to build a Windows executable. Or, if you're really trying to program for DOS then you'll have to get rid of all of those Windows libraries.

Comment: @Michael, yes, they do exist

Comment: @Michael, I tried to use `link`, but it just doesn't generate .exe file and doesn't show console where I choose settings for .exe file

Comment: What was the exact command you used, and what was the error message(s) that you got? To link a Windows console application you should use something like `link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE tat.obj`

Comment: @Michael, `link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE tat.obj` still doesn't compile the .exe file.
But when I try to compile with `link16 /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE tat.obj` it outputs this
`C:\masm32\include\masm32rt.inc(33) : warning A4011: multiple .MODEL directives found : .MODEL ignored` and this `LINK : warning L4017: /SUBSYSTEM : unrecognized option name; option ignored`

Comment: @Michael
And when I compile with just `link16 tat.obj` it outputs also this
`LINK : warning L4051: \masm32\lib\masm32.lib : cannot find library                                                      Enter new file spec:                                                                                                    LINK : warning L4051: \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib : cannot find library                                                       Enter new file spec:                                                                                                 `

Comment: @Michael and the similar warnings, I can enter them all if it's needed